# do we need a "local server" like tomcat to use phpmyadmin?

Tags: php, mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I already have mysql installed, but I have not installed anything else that simulates a server on my computer.

Is it possible to install and use phpmyadmin without having a local server running on my computer?

Answer (score 2):

not possible, you need a webserver to deliver the web-page to a browser

Answer (score 2):

You'll need a webserver, see the documentation if in doubt: http://www.phpmyadmin.net/documentation/

Answer (score 1):

You **need** some webserver which can serve static files and execute PHP scripts to use phpMyAdmin.

Answer (score 1):

If you don´t want to install a web-server and php, you can install for example [MySQL Workbench](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/5.2.html) to manage just mysql.

For phpmyadmin you will need a web-server.

Answer (score 0):

Actually you have to install servers like WAMP, XAMP or TOMCAT. They deplye the admin site for phymyadmin. So if you don't install an application on your pc, how would you use it, untill and unless you are using on another server.